# Google chrome plays mkv but firefox doesn't, why?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, video

I have a web video player that plays mkv and mp4 videos, everything runs well on google chrome but firefox only plays mp4 ones, when I try to click one of mkv videos it says: **Video format or MIME type is not supported** this is my video script, just in case you need it to find out what's wrong: http://pastebin.com/Vrvqt8wq

So what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

[Firefox simply does not support Matroska](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) natively, except for the subset of it that is WEBM.

As far as I know, Chrome does not *officially* support or endorse Matroska either, but it happens to work.